# Email a Formatted List to a user(s)

Tags: list, email

I have a Formatted list complete for Rich text (Colored status fields). he list will very isn size from several rows to 25 rows.  I want to send the list via email just as it looks in SharePoint.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**If you're writing code:**
Not as Rich text, but [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454274.aspx) sends the body as HTML

**If you're creating a SharePoint Designer Workflow**
Even though it doesn't tell it the Body of the Email users action allows full HTML like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I am not familiar with implementing this procedure and do not know how to invoke it.  Can you point me to where i can learn how to implement within my Sharepoint workflow?

Comment: What kind of workflow? SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: Sharepoint Designer. I am not really versed on Visual Basic programming nor do I know where or how to begin with this.

Comment: Thanks Per for your help. I see the Full HTML listing, but can i actually link the SharePoint List in the Body of this email?  I want the email body to look like the list displays when I veiwing in Sharepoint?

Comment: No I'm sorry but not without having someone build a custom action. You can insert any text you can get hold of into the body, but I can't see how you should be able to get the view without custom code.